# How to determine the most efficient index range size to grab?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, indexing, database-performance

I am repeatedly selecting chunks of data from a large table. How do I determine the a size for the range of values to select that allows me to make a few trips to the table as possible but keep from having to do a full table scan on the table each time.

Example queries, with a size of 1000:

```
SELECT id, data_col 
FROM table_with_data 
WHERE  id BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 
ORDER BY id;

SELECT id, data_col 
FROM table_with_data 
WHERE  id BETWEEN 2001 AND 3000 
ORDER BY id;

SELECT id, data_col 
FROM table_with_data 
WHERE  id BETWEEN 3001 AND 4000 
ORDER BY id;
```

*Additional background if needed:*
In my specific case I am trying to quickly pull values from an Oracle database and load into a CASSANDRA database using Hector.  I have 20-40 threads going at once that are selecting the data and loading the results.  While doing some performance testing I am finding some optimal "batch" sizes for the table today.  However the table grows slowly overtime and I wanted to see if there was a better way to determine the size as my testing is not providing super consistent results.

Comment: What is your bottleneck?  Are you sure that you wouldn't be better off running a single query that does a full scan of the table using parallel query?

Comment: how do you insert to cassandra with each chunk?

Comment: @JustinCave I originally started with a single query, but found several threads all running smaller queries allowed the data move to happen more than 10x faster.  Now trying to optimize that path.

Comment: @Sebas, using Hector to insert into Cassandra.  That part is flying, I am just trying to optimize the selection in Oracle as that is still the slowest part.